# Can't boot into Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, kernel

Today I installed Ubuntu 13.04 by doing clean install but I could only see purple screen. Then I installed nvidia drivers using root, now I can see only background image and Unity is not loading. I think Compiz is not loading too since I have no window borders. How to fix this.

EDIT:

I ran nvidia-xconfig and got error: "Unable to write to directory /etc/x11". Also I ran unity --replace and got error: Can't launch openGl (something like that)

EDIT:

Downloaded image using torrent and then reinstalled Ubuntu, now it works, also during installation I checked option for downloading updated during installation.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 login and type unity --replace and post what error do you get!

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285627/unity-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: That's not it, I think my problem are graphics card drivers. I already installed nvidia-current but is seems they are not activated, so how to activate drivers. When I ran command from above link I got error about openGl, it can't be loaded. And I have really low resolution with screen flickering.

Comment: I ran nvidia-xconfig and got error: "Unable to write to directory /etc/x11". Also I ran unity --replace and got error about openGl like before. So this question is different from link you posted, please do not close it.

Comment: @Alen You should put the updates in your question itself (that is, move them from comments).