# Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit broken unity and compiz after installing nvidia driver

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz, 64-bit

my Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit broken unity and compiz after installing nvidia driver, i've tried the below command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

but i get:

```
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - info: Starting plugin: core
unity-panel-service: no process found
compiz (core) - Error: Another window manager is already running on screen: 0
compiz (core) - Info: Stoping plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core
```

i found a page [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285627/unity-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-13-04) saying that reboot if it doesn't work right away. same broken unity after reboot.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make nvidia config:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Then restart your login manager.

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

If it does not help, try to load nvidia kernel module manually:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
```

And even if it does not help, you have to blacklist nouveau module:

```
echo "blacklist nouveau" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then restart and your problem should disappear. If not, check if your card is supported by the driver.