# Ubuntu-desktop: unmet dependencies

Tags: unity, 13.04, gnome

I tried to install Gnome on ubuntu 13.04 using these guide (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/gnome-3-8-ppa-for-ubuntu-gnome). It didn't work very well (there were some glitches), so I tried uninstall it.

I followed the instructions, but when I went back to Unity it was "ugly" and I couldn't see the desktop (I had files there, but they weren't shown).

I reinstalled gnome again, and purge everything again, and I *think* I also uninstalled ubuntu-deskop (following advice from another page)

Now unity is more or less ok, but I can't still see my Desktop, and some programs like evince are lost. If I try to `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: evince but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: seahorse but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: software-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: deja-dup-backend-ubuntuone but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: empathy but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-control-center-unity but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: thunderbird-gnome-support but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ubuntuone-client-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ubuntuone-control-panel-qt but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I cannot install, for example, evince, because I get:

```
daniel@daniel-linux:~$ sudo apt-get install evince
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 evince : Depends: evince-common (< 3.7) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu4~raring1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried `apt-get clean`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get autoremove` also... I've also followed the steps given here [Gnome 3.8 affects Unity in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343467/gnome-3-8-affects-unity-in-ubuntu-13-04) , but I still have the same problem.

Any idea on how can I get everything working again?

Comment: Try removing evince-common with `sudo apt-get remove evince-common`, then reinstall evince.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: Have you removed the gnome3 PPA?

Answer (score -1):

To solve your 'unmet dependencies' issue, I suggest using 

 `sudo apt-get -f install` .