# Compiz is crashing on startup in Ubuntu 13.04 after installing steam-login

Tags: unity, compiz, steam

I installed steam-login from [here](https://github.com/thor27/steam-login) and it worked just fine. Then I went back to Unity and it wouldn't load Unity anymore. When I tried running compiz from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> command line it gave me the output below.

When I googled the first error line, I found [this page](https://forum.ubuntu-gr.org/viewtopic.php?p=288512). It's in greek but it does mention xfwm4 which steam-login makes use of so I'm thinking that could be the culprit. Any suggestions on how to reset things? I tried [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285627/unity-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-13-04), that didn't do it, as well as some of the commands in the other greek web page and that didn't work either.

```
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
unity-panel-service: no process found
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:580 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Autopilot.Introspection' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:580 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Debug.Logging' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
Xlib:  extension "XINERAMA" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "XINERAMA" missing on display ":0".
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-impress.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
ERROR 2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib-gio <unknown>:0 g_file_monitor_set_rate_limit: assertion `G_IS_FILE_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
ERROR 2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.launcher.icon.trash TrashLauncherIcon.cpp:62 Could not create file monitor for trash uri: Operation not supported
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:580 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
Xlib:  extension "XINERAMA" missing on display ":0".
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:580 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 invalid (NULL) pointer instance
ERROR 2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
WARN  2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 invalid (NULL) pointer instance
ERROR 2013-09-27 00:52:55 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
**
IBUS:ERROR:ibusconfig.c:237:ibus_config_get_value: assertion failed: (IBUS_IS_CONFIG (config))
Aborted (core dumped)
WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting compiz by executing the command below:

> rm -r ~/.config/compiz-1; rm -r ~/.compiz

Then give restart.

Comment: That fixed it. However there's still a bug in steam-login or one of the dependencies that it uses, because as soon as I log back in with steam-login, the behavior is exhibited again and I have to remove those folders to reset compiz again. I filed the issue [here](https://github.com/thor27/steam-login/issues/12)

Comment: I think this has something to do with your steam installation. If you downloaded steam.deb file from the web site, remove that and install steam from Ubuntu software center.  If you installed Steam from Ubuntu software center, do the other way around. Reset Steam as well. rm -r ~/.steam

Comment: steam-launcher that was installed was from the beta. It got updated to the ubuntu repo version when it came out. I uninstalled and reinstalled steam from the software center but I'm not gonna rm -r right now since I'll have to reinstall all my games again.

Comment: It seems I didn't have to rm-r ~/.steam including all the folders pointed to in the symlinks. Just reinstalling the steam-launcher package with the one from the ubuntu software center and removing the steam folder only fixed it.

It works fine now.

Comment: However, this doesn't solve my problem. Tried a lot of ways.

Comment: I had same problem on 14.10 and this fixed it. Thanks.